# what extension to use for setting a file name using log4j

Tags: java, logging

is there any documentation that while i am using the log4j, what will be the file extension

```
    #Normal Log File
log4j.appender.logfile=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.logfile.File=/logs/apps/application.txt
log4j.appender.logfile.MaxFileSize=100KB
log4j.appender.logfile.MaxBackupIndex=100
log4j.appender.logfile.layout=com.log4j.WebSpherePatternLayout
log4j.appender.logfile.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [~C | ~N | ~S] %-5p (%F:%M():%L)  - %m%n
```

any specific extension or i can use extension like .txt , .log, .out etc ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use any extension file based on your preference. Based on your configuration when it reach 100KB the file will rotate to `application.txt.1`. `log` extension is preferable since the purpose of the file is for `logging`